# Foldable IntSet

Tags: haskell, set, foldable

For me, an integer set seems to be a foldable data structure.
Why is `Data.IntSet` not an instance of `Foldable`?

My actual intention is to use `find` on an `IntSet`.
How can I implement find for `Data.IntSet`?

Comment: `Data.IntSet` may not be `Foldable`, but it does provide `foldl` and `foldr` implementations. There's also a `member` function which performs your typical `find` operation. If you wanted to implement your own `find` function, there are `LookupLE`, `LookupGT` etc functions which would let you perform a binary search. Workaround though.

Comment: `class Foldable` applies to `* -> *` kinds, and `IntSet` is a `*` kind.

Comment: @ephemient you should post that as the answer. Relevant: `IntSet` _is_ an instance of [`MonoFoldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`IntSet` can't be `Foldable` from `base` package because it doesn't have kind `* -> *`.

```
ghci> :t foldr
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
ghci> :k Foldable
Foldable :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
ghci> import Data.IntSet (IntSet)
ghci> :k IntSet
IntSet :: *
```

In simple words, to be instance of `Foldable` from `base` you data type should be parametrized by some type variable. If you want to use some operation on `IntSet` you should use some function from `Data.IntSet` module where all specialized versions implemented.

But I want to add that there exist version of `Foldable` which `IntSet` can instantiate (and [we actually did this in our library](https://github.com/serokell/universum/blob/5ced025bfa522beba133d35e2093cd81dd21726e/src/Containers.hs#L172) and this was done earlier with [`MonoFoldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mono-traversable-1.0.2.1/docs/Data-MonoTraversable.html#t:MonoFoldable)). You just need to implement your abstractions properly:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

type family Element t
type instance Element (f a)  = a
type instance Element Text   = Char
type instance Element IntSet = Int

class ProperFoldable t where
    foldr :: (Element t -> b -> b) -> b -> t -> b
```

**UPDATE** (adding `find` by request):

You can't implement `find :: (a -> Bool) -> IntSet -> Maybe a` because of `a` type variable. Can you answer question «What is `a`?»? `IntSet` is not polymorphic container. It contains only `Int`s. So maximum you can implement is `find :: (Int -> Bool) -> IntSet -> Maybe Int`. And there's no efficient way to implement this function, only by converting `IntSet` to list like this:

```
import           Data.Foldable (find)
import           Data.IntSet (IntSet)
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS

intSetFind :: (Int -> Bool) -> IntSet -> Maybe Int
intSetFind predicate = find predicate . IS.elems
```

Comment: `Element` should probably be an associated type family. :)

Comment: @Alec is there any reason why associated type family better? It's not obvious to me when to choose such option...

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Can you add how to implement `find :: (a -> Bool) -> IntSet -> Maybe a` ?

Comment: @Shersh Associating the type family gives you a warning when you declare an instance of `ProperFoldable` without also the type family instance. Otherwise, you are much more likely to end up with stuck type family applications.

Comment: @Isund I've updated answer with `find` implementation.

Comment: To make associating the type pay, add a default definition. `type Element t :: a; type Element (f a) = a`. Personally, I prefer to make the element type the first class parameter as well, with an equality constraint.

Comment: I have to delete my previous comment saying everything is clear. I understand now that a datatype must have kind * -> * to be foldable and that there exists a way to make `IntSet` foldable with `MonoFoldable`. What I don't understand is why you can't have a function that efficiently searches for the first `Int` in an `IntSet` that satisfies some predicate. In a procedural language, It would make no difference if the container was polymorphic or not. Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm new to haskell.

Comment: @Isund What your predicate exactly does? If you want to find number equals to some other number then there is and efficient way. But what if you want to find any prime number of just even number? You have function of type `Int -> Bool` and you don't know anything about it inside `find` function. All you have is list of sorted `Int`s. For example, I don't know how to implement `find even` efficiently (faster than _O(n)_) for sorted list of integers.

Comment: The function can have linear complexity, I'm not saying anything about the predicate. But your proposed version of `find` is first converting the set into a list so the complexity should be *2n* instead of *n* worst-case If I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Isund The complexity would be _2n_ if first list was stored as an intermediate value and only then traversal of `find` function happen. But Haskell is lazy language. You can think of `IS.elems` as of lazy iterator which produces values of `IntSet` on demand and `find` function calling this iterator while necessary. So in practice there would be no _2n_. Always lower.