# How to implement default associated type family for OVERLAPPABLE instance, monomorphic container and newtype wrapper?

Tags: haskell, type-families

I had the following Haskell code:

```
type family Element t

class ToList t where
    toList :: t -> [Element t]
```

It was suggested to me earlier to make `Element` an associated type family: [Foldable IntSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45424976/foldable-intset/45425178)

I tried to implement this approach. But it doesn't work for my case. Here is the whole code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Prelude hiding (toList)
import qualified Data.Foldable as Foldable (toList)
import Data.Text (Text, unpack)

class ToList t where
    type Element t :: *
    toList :: t -> [Element t]

-- | This instance makes 'ToList' compatible and overlappable by 'Foldable'.
instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Foldable f => ToList (f a) where
    type Element (f a) = a
    toList = Foldable.toList

instance ToList Text where
    type Element Text = Char
    toList = unpack

newtype WrappedList l = WrappedList l

instance ToList l => ToList (WrappedList l) where
    type Element (WrappedList l) = Element l
    toList (WrappedList l) = toList l
```

When I compile this code with `GHC-8.2.2` I see the following error:

```
Element.hs:14:10: error:
    Conflicting family instance declarations:
      Element (f a) = a -- Defined at Element.hs:14:10
      Element (WrappedList l) = Element l -- Defined at Element.hs:24:10
   |
14 |     type Element (f a) = a
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How I can fix this error? I have no idea how make this compilable with associated type family...

Comment: You can't - open type families are not allowed to overlap. You could use a multiparameter typeclass. However, I don't see the purpose of the `WrappedList` instance.

Comment: @user240738 I’m going to guess it’s a simple sanity check to make sure a marginally complicated type can be an instance as well as simple ones.

Comment: @user2407038 Another solution that can satisfy me is to have default implementation of `type Element` type family and have an ability to override this implementation. @HTNW point regarding sanity check is true :) But in my case I have `class ToList t => Container t` where `Container` has ~15 methods. And this `WrappedList` wrapper implements all `Container` methods through `Container` instance for `[a]`. Might be useful if you want to use `Container` methods but don't want to implement ~15 methods for your data type.

Comment: @user2407038 Answer to this questions suggests to use _ default associated injective type family_ but I don't see how can I use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206079/associated-data-families-and-overlapping-instances

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The essential problem is that you can't use to type class overlap to make type families which overlap. It simply doesn't make sense - a type family computes a type from an input type, and the resulting type may not depend on how the compiler picks a type class instance (or else it wouldn't be a function - since the output of a function may only depend on the input). This problem is quite common, but how you solve it depends entirely on your specific use case.

The simplest solution is to give your default implementation using `DefaultSignatures`. Note that associated type families can have defaults as well:

```
type family ElementDefault (t :: *) :: * where
  ElementDefault (f a) = a

class ToList t where
    type Element t :: *
    type Element t = ElementDefault t

    toList :: t -> [Element t]
    default toList :: (Foldable f, t ~ f a, Element t ~ a) => t -> [Element t]
    toList = Foldable.toList
```

This allows you to write instances for all `Foldable` types without giving the implementation:

```
instance ToList [a]
instance ToList (Maybe a)
-- etc...
```

---

If you want to avoid writing such instances (even the instance heads), you need to move the associated type into the class instance head. Since it is only classes which may overlap, not open type families, doing so allows the 'element' type to also be overlapping.

```
class ToList t e | t -> e where
  toList :: t -> [e]

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} (a ~ a', Foldable f) => ToList (f a) a' where
  toList = Foldable.toList

instance ToList Text Char where
  toList = unpack

instance ToList l a => ToList (WrappedList l) a where
  toList (WrappedList l) = toList l
```

---

The simplest way to provide multiple default definitions is to provide them outside of the class. If you have 15 class functions, this indeed can be tedious. In such a situation, I would implement the class with a record:

```
data ToList' t e = ToList'
  { toList' :: t -> [e] {- 14 more fields... -} }

class ToList t where
  type Element t 
  toList_impl :: ToList' t (Element t)

-- For consumers of ToList
toList :: ToList t => t -> [Element t]
toList = toList' toList_impl

instance ToList Text where
  type Element Text = Char
  toList_impl = ToList' unpack

toList_Foldable_default :: Foldable f => ToList' (f a) a
toList_Foldable_default = ToList' Foldable.toList

toList_Wrapped_list :: ToList l => ToList' l (Element l)
toList_Wrapped_list = ToList' toList
```

With this approach, you can dispense with the typeclass entirely; its only remaining use is to get instance uniqueness.

Comment: Thanks! That was very useful. Now I see the problem.